# Can I stop getting invites in Calendar.app for events i'm not invited to?

Tags: calendar, ical, google-calendar, google-apps

I'm using [Google Apps](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/) at work and it adds a bunch of calendars for my coworkers to Calendar, which is exactly what I want.  However I keep getting invitation notifications for events I'm not actually invited to.  In order to clear the notification I have to Accept, Decline, or respond with Maybe.

Is there anyway to stop this?  A lot of them are duplicates. What is even more confusing is some events actually behave the way I expect where they just notify me and I can only respond with OK.

For the life of me I can't figure out whats going on.  I wish I knew why some events behave differently.

Bonus points if you know of something like [Event Merge for Google Calendar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/event-merge-for-google-ca/idehaflielbgpaokehlhidbjlehlfcep/related?hl=en) that works in Calendar.app. Because the duplicate events are also annoying even though I know it's just that the event is on multiple calendars.  It would be nice to collapse them.

At this point I'd even be open to suggestions for a better Calendar app provided it handled this better.

Comment: Your Mac calendar is passive in this situation. It is the Google calendar that sends all the Invites. Check your settings there.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Would you share a solution?